# Use apt-get fails on docker python:2.7.12-wheezy image

Tags: docker

I am trying to use the python image to run a python script, however, I also need gawk on the same image.  So I am trying to first install gawk.  (why gawk? the version of mawk on the machine by default does not have the options I need.)

I get the error "E: Unable to locate package gawk" and when I googled that it said that I needed to update `/etc/apt/sources.list`, however I was also unable to do that. (tried `echo '<src>'>>/etc/apt/sources.list` and it returned no such file.)

Here is what I ran:

```
$ docker run -w $WORKSPACE -v $WORKSPACE:$WORKSPACE python:2.7.12-wheezy apt-
get install gawk
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package gawk
```

It is not a network issue, I can run update, and wget, etc.

```
$ docker run -w $WORKSPACE -v $WORKSPACE:$WORKSPACE python:2.7.12-wheezy apt-get update 
Get:1 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg [1554 B]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release [39.0 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg [2373 B]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages [565 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org wheezy-updates Release.gpg [1554 B]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org wheezy Release [191 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org wheezy-updates Release [155 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org wheezy/main amd64 Packages [7634 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages [7481 B]
Fetched 8597 kB in 14s (584 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
```

It seems to work fine in interactive mode:

```
$ docker run -it python:2.7.12-wheezy bash
root@0d7daa6b998e:/# apt-get update
... edited ..         
Reading package lists... Done
root@0d7daa6b998e:/# apt-get install gawk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
... edited ...
Fetched 1001 kB in 2s (444 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
... edited output down...
Setting up gawk (1:4.0.1+dfsg-2.1) ...
```

Comment: Did you run `update` first? Also if that file doesn't exist can you create it?

Comment: The file does exist, and I can run update.

Comment: There's some incomplete story here, so just getting context. You know that you're running completely separate containers above right? What if you do all this in one container shell (using `docker run -it -w /test python:2.7.12-wheezy bash`) ?

Comment: It's because you're creating new containers everytime. Only in the interactive one you're doing everything in one container. If you want to run several steps (update, echo, install, etc...) it would be better to build a Dockerfile using python:2.7.12-wheezy as a base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run each command in a separate container (new container everytime you do `docker run...`) so essentially you're starting a container (e.g. `A`) and updating apt, then running a completely new container (e.g. `B`) and doing `apt-get install`. `B` has no knowledge of `A`. The answer is to create a new Dockerfile based on the original image you want, with the additional commands as `RUN` instructions, for example:

```
FROM python:2.7.12-wheezy
RUN \
     apt-get update && apt-get install \
         gawk && \
     apt-get clean && \
     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Then do `docker build -t my-new-wheezy-base .` and use that as your new image (`FROM my-new-wheezy-base` etc...).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your error is adding to your apt sources from this comment:

> (tried echo ''>>/etc/apt/sources.list and it returned no such file.)

If you ran that like this:

```
docker run some-image echo '<src>'>>/etc/apt/sources.list
```

That will try to write to the /etc/apt/sources.list on your host (the shell where you run `docker` catches the `>>` and tries to write the output of the docker command. There are various ways to output to the file inside the container, including running it interactively, or escaping the shell characters and processing the line with an `eval`.

```
docker run some-image /bin/sh -c eval echo '<src>'\>\>/etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: This was helpful.  However, now that I found that it works fine interactively (base don the comments from johnharris85, I do not think I need to add anything, I just had to run update and then install.